# Objective C Primitive Types

Tags: objective-c, pointers, foundation, primitive-types

I've been reading about the Objective-C datatypes and all the primitive types it inherits from C.

Data types like bool are inherited but type-def to `BOOL`, so declared like:

```
BOOL myBOOL;
```

Where as `NSString` is declared like:

```
NSString * myString;
```

My doubt is how do I know when to use `*` and when not to? Primitive types don't need `*`, I know that, but that's a little confusing because

Eg:

```
NSString * myString;
```

Where as

```
NSInteger myInt;
```

So the doubt really is, I understand using * with Objective C's own data types but no `*` for primitive types.

But in this example above `NSInteger` is a primitive type. So how do I differentiate between primitive and non-primitive data types ? (NS prefix clearly isn't the correct answer)

Comment: Read the documentation.  That's the only way to know.  You use the `*` to denote that you're declaring a pointer.

Comment: @nhgrif: I know, but I've been giving interviews recently and have been asked to write stuff on the whiteboard. Is there anyway I can know otherwise?

Comment: Memorization is your only option if you can't look it up in the documentation. There's actually very few types starting with `NS` that are primitive types.

Comment: There are tons of types with all sorts of prefixes that don't require pointers.  Each abbreviation is basically a separate framework, and basically every framework has structs, enums, or simple typedefs like `NSInterger` (`NSTimeInterval`, `CGFloat`, `CLLocationDistance`, `UIViewAutoResizing` just to name a few...)

Comment: For what it's worth, the two most common ones are `NSInteger` and `CGFloat`.  These are not object references and do not require the `*`.  Anything beyond this, if you're honest about your experience level on your resume, no one should really expect you to have it memorized for white board coding really...

Comment: I think you've discovered why programs are written in Xcode instead of on a whiteboard.  :)